# Shipping Question.

Tags: fair-division

I need to work out the most effective way of shipping the following amount of boxes in different containers.

- 889210 boxes
- 666911 boxes
- 444606 boxes
- 222305 boxes

The largest container can hold 4004 boxes
The medium container can hold 3432 boxes
The smallest container can hold 1688 boxes

I need to know the least amount of containers needed to move the boxes in the most effcient method. Containers have to be sent regardless of how full they are so the more boxes in them the better.

Thanks in advance,
Kristian

Comment: For a second, I thought you wrote "Shqipping Question," and I was wondering why you were writing about Albanian.

Comment: No afraid not. Just need some help with the above for work.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the no. of boxes by the limit per large container. The quotient is the no. of large containers required.

Divide the remainder by the limit per medium container. The quotient is the no. of medium containers required.

Divide this remainder by the limit per small container. If there is a remainder, the no. of small containers required is the quotient + 1, otherwise it is just the quotient.